# JSON.NET ignores all my properties without JsonProperty attribute

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a `GameBoard` class, which has 2 methods for saving and loading:

```
    public void Save(string pFilePath)
    {
        var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(pFilePath, s);
    }

    public static GameBoard Load(string pFilePath)
    {
        var s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pFilePath);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GameBoard>(s);
    }
```

Those are the properties of my `GameBoard` class:

```
    #region Fields

    public int Width { get; protected set; }

    public int Height { get; protected set; }

    public GameBoardCell[,] Cells { get; protected set; }

    public bool WallSurrounded { get; set; }

    #endregion
```

The `Save` method works great, and this is the content:

> {"Width":3,"Height":3,"Cells":[[{"Content":0,"Ball":{"ColorID":0,"ID":"4481e52d-76fc-4335-805b-c47e36e3d57d"},"Target":null},{"Content":1,"Ball":null,"Target":null},{"Content":0,"Ball":null,"Target":null}],[{"Content":0,"Ball":null,"Target":null},{"Content":0,"Ball":null,"Target":null},{"Content":0,"Ball":null,"Target":null}],[{"Content":0,"Ball":null,"Target":null},{"Content":1,"Ball":null,"Target":null},{"Content":0,"Ball":null,"Target":{"ColorID":0,"ID":"aaf6f4ae-0a1a-4c3d-9608-f13ae9c4bba7"}}]],"WallSurrounded":true}

However, when I use `Load` method with the same file, all my properties are either `null` or default values (0 for ints).

I have to add `[JsonProperty]` to each of my property for it to work properly. I have used Json.NET before, and I remember that I didn't have to add any attribute. Is this intent change from Json.NET (I just get 6.0.6 from Nuget for this new project), or I did something wrong?

Comment: could you share relevant parts of your `BoardGame` class, please

Comment: Are you using immutable classes or immutable collections?  Did you set `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]` anywhere?

Comment: You wrote, "The Save method works great, and this is the content".  But all the `Cell` properties shown in the json you posted have default values.  So, is `Save` working correctly?

Comment: @dbc No, all the classes only contains basic primitive types and two-dimension array. And I do not use any attribute anywhere (Json related or not).

Comment: @dbc and sorry, I did save a blank 3x3 game board. I saved another game board, and updated the post. I added a Ball and a Target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON.NET ignores `private`, `protected` or `internal` property setters. Convert the properties to `public`, or decorate them with attributes.

https://json.codeplex.com/discussions/222774

Comment: Thank you, so that is the reason. I cannot change them to `public`. So I guess I have to decorate them then.

Comment: I suggest using `[DataContract]` instead of `[JsonObject]` and `[DataMember]` instead of `[JsonProperty]` for compatibility reasons.